# Setting up Inverse Kinematics with non-standard bones

Tags: animation, blender

So I'm trying to make new animations for a fairly old game. I've managed to get Inverse Kinematics to work with the skeleton by stretching the bones to connect to each other, but I can't use the animation in-game Because the bones revert to their original orientation, which breaks the animation. Is it possible to set up inverse kinematics for a skeleton like this or do I need to do the poses by hand?

[Image of bones or joints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m1ls.png)

[Full skeleton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDhDe.png)

I have tried setting up inverse kinematics in multiple ways, such as adding new bones to connect the joints and trying that way, but it just seems to make the model distort rather than actually work as an animation tool.

Answer (score 0):

Have you edited all of the bones "Roll values" to make sure they are oriented correctly in Blender?

If you are using Unity, then you would need to Retarget the Animation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Retargeting.html

Information such as vertex number and position are vital for animation data. Any changes to this information can invalidate it, disrupting the animation.

To the best of my knowledge, the most straightforward method to handle this issue is by utilising Animation/Bone Retargeting features in the respective software/game engine you are using. This technique involves sharing a linked avatar or an Animation Controller between the two distinct models.

Best of luck!